# Java RMI odd/inconsistent Activatable.register behavior - UnknownGroupException

Tags: java, rmi

Trying to use RMI and having odd issue.

The code below I have snipped the catches.  There are no exceptions in them - the code progress properly until:
reportServerRemote = Activatable.register(_desc);

When I run the code below **THE FIRST TIME**, I get
Exception: java.rmi.activation.UnknownGroupException: group unknown
on the call: reportServerRemote = Activatable.register(_desc);
Note that I have requested and set the _groupID.

When I run it the second time, it works.  I thought it might be some kind of timing issue, and have add delays and retries at various spots, but to no effect.

```
    ActivationSystem _activationSystem = null;
    try {
        String _lookMeUp = "//:" + RMID_ACTIVATION_SYSTEM_PORT + "/java.rmi.activation.ActivationSystem";
        _activationSystem =
                (ActivationSystem) Naming.lookup(_lookMeUp);
        ActivationGroup.setSystem(_activationSystem);


    ActivationGroupDesc _groupDesc = new ActivationGroupDesc(null, null);


    ActivationGroupID _groupID = null;
    try {
        _groupID = _activationSystem.registerGroup(_groupDesc);


    ActivationDesc _desc = null;
    try {
        _desc = new ActivationDesc(_groupID, ReportServer.class.getName(),
                                null,
                                new MarshalledObject(LicenseUtil.loadSerialAndLicense()));



reportServerRemote = Activatable.register(_desc);
```

Exception: java.rmi.activation.UnknownGroupException: group unknown

Comment: What Java version are you using? Activation has been removed. Refer to [JEP 385](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/385).

Comment: java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be within that same `try` block. Don't write one `try/catch` system after another.

Comment: Thanks.  good tip!

Answer (score 0):

I added a looping check after the initial registerGroup call.  If it failed I tried again.  It always seems to work on the 2nd try, but I left at 10 tries - just in case.

```
ActivationGroupID _groupID = null;
    try {
        _groupID = _activationSystem.registerGroup(_groupDesc);
    } catch (Exception pE) {
        pE.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Unable to determine groupID for group description \"" + _groupDesc + "\"", pE);
        throw new Exception("Got exception while attempting to obtain group id. Exception: " + pE);
    }

    /*
     * Sometimes it does not work the first time.  Keep trying.
     */
    boolean _needToRegisterGroup = true;
    for ( int i = 0; _needToRegisterGroup && i< 10; i++) {
        _needToRegisterGroup = false;
        try {
            // See if it's there
            ActivationGroupDesc _t = _activationSystem.getActivationGroupDesc(_groupID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Try again
            _groupID = _activationSystem.registerGroup(_groupDesc);

            // Wait a bit before checking
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException pIE) {
            }
            _needToRegisterGroup = true;
        }
    }

    if ( _needToRegisterGroup ) {
        throw new Exception("Never able to RegisterGroup with RMID.");
    }
```